# Odoo: how to delete the saved model on cancelling/leaving form?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a form on odoo for scheduling appointments where the user clicks on a button to search available appointment slots.

When the button is clicked, the model is saved, that's how odoo works and I could not work around that.

But if the user gives up on scheduling the appointment, the model is already saved... So I need to delete it from the database if the user leaves the form, or clicks "cancel".

How do I do it?

Comment: when you click a button odoo saves the form after that you are editing a created record. Its not logical to delete a file when you cancel an edit of a record. You can try giving your button action in onchange of any field, so the file will not be saved

Comment: @Amal I tried doing this, but I have to change the options of a Selection field, and I found out it's not possible (changing the available options won't update the selection widget). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried many2one instead of selection and change the domain.

Comment: For future reference, I didn't go with that solution, so I never found a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A nice work around is to use The  `active` field if this field is False Odoo by default will not show this record. and you can register a `ir.cron` to delete this records or leave them.

Hope you get the idea

Comment: that makes sense.. if I don't come up with a better solution for the whole thing I might try that